# C# + Excel. NamedRange.Formula

Tags: c#, excel

Is there a limit on the length of the formula?
If I use:

```
string form = "=ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"101\";\"цту\";ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"102\";\"сзту\";ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"103\";\"юту\";ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"104\";\"пту\";ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"105\";\"уту\";ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"106\";\"сту\";ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"107\";\"двту\";\"скту\")))))))";
        xlWorkSheet.Range["D2"].FormulaLocal = form;
```

That's all okay.

But if I use:

```
string form = "=ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"101\";\"цту\";ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"102\";\"сзту\";ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"103\";\"юту\";ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"104\";\"пту\";ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"105\";\"уту\";ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"106\";\"сту\";ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"107\";\"двту\";ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;3)=\"108\";\"скту\";\"fuck\"))))))))";
        xlWorkSheet.Range["D2"].FormulaLocal = form;
```

That error takes off:

HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: If i use this formula in Excel, everything works.

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel? 14

Answer (score 1):

It seems there *is* a limit to the length of string written to `.FormulaLocal` (and other forms of `.Formula`)

By experimentation in VBA, it apears to be 258 characters.  I can find some references on various blogs to this suggesting a limit of about 256, but can find an official source.

Interestingly, this limit doesn't apply if the string doesn't include a `=` prefix.

Tested on Excel 2010.

For completness, here's the test code

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim s As String, ss As String, f As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set r = [A20]
    s = "=""This is a test of string length: "
    ss = "z"
    On Error GoTo EH
    For i = 1 To 350
        f = s & ss & """"
        Debug.Print ""
        Debug.Print Len(f)
        r.FormulaLocal = f
        Debug.Print "OK"
        ss = "z" & ss
    Next
Exit Sub
EH:
    Debug.Print "Fail"
End Sub
```

And the last few lines of the result

```
 257 
OK

 258 
OK

 259 
Fail
```

---

It gets weirder: this code works

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim s As String, ss As String, f As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set r = [A20]
    s = "IF(A1=1,AAA999,FALSE)"
    ss = "z"
    r.FormulaLocal = "=" & s
    On Error GoTo EH
    For i = 1 To 60
        Debug.Print ""
        Debug.Print Len(r.FormulaLocal)
        r.FormulaLocal = Replace(r.FormulaLocal, "AAA999", s)
        Debug.Print "OK"
        Debug.Print Len(r.FormulaLocal)
    Next
Exit Sub
EH:
    Debug.Print "Fail"
End Sub
```

What this does is builds up the formula up in sections, each as a valid Formula in its own right.  Fails at about 1000 characters (1024 maybe).

Answer (score 0):

Check the following page for the Excel limits:

https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

In particular, it says:

> Length of formula contents - 8,192 characters
>
> Internal length of formula - 16,384 bytes

Comment: but my length from 2nd example is 266 characters... no?